# How do I define functions in TraditionalForm?

Tags: functions, traditional-form

I'd like to be able to define functions (at least simple ones that *Mathematica* can otherwise understand) using `TraditionalForm`; but this seems to require the use of an underscore.

For example, I'd like to be able to have something like

$$f(x) = x^2$$

correspond to

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

but *Mathematica* seems to require

$$f(x\text{_}) = x^2$$

which goes a long way towards defeating the whole purpose.

Is there, perhaps, a way to define some formatting that's less obtrusive, and more "conventionally notational" than the underscore that could correspond to the `TraditionalForm` underscore (and thus resolve any ambiguities)?

Comment: Even if it is possible, it's probably not a very good idea to indulge in code gymnastics just to be able to make your code look like a latex document. At some point it will break and you'll be left wondering what went wrong. I'd strongly urge keeping code in `StandardForm` and use `TraditionalForm` only for output formatting or in labels/text, etc. Besides, how will you differentiate the $f(x)$ in `f[x_] = 2` and `f[x] = 2`? Both are valid definitions, but your usage above makes it ambiguous. (note, I didn't down vote).

Comment: @rm-rf: If that were in fact my goal, I'd be using a different tool. The goal is simply to not have to repeat simple equations that are more readable as `TraditionalForm` in the cases, like the one above, where the intent is clear.

Comment: No, the intent is not clear — see the example in my above comment (I was editing it when you posted yours).

Comment: There is another ambiguity: How to distinguish between "set f(x) = x^2" and "is f(x) = x^2 ?". To overcome these ambiguities, some good heuristics would be needed (just like when trying to read traditional math notation). And they would be wrong sometimes.

Comment: @rm-rf: This may be a more limited case than I'm imagining, but one scenario is: I have a list of simple functions for, say, converting between units or coordinate systems, and I'm doing no analysis (in the mathematical sense) with them, just simple calculations. I'd like to be able to define all of those functions once, in `TraditionalForm` and have them work, without having to redefine them in (less readable) `StandardForm`.

Comment: @AndrewMoylan: Yes, my original question was incomplete, I'd just be happy with more "traditional" formatting that serves to make the intent clear. (See edit.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius what I do is I typeset in normal form my input  and when needed I select the input cell and `Convert to Traditionnal Form` from the `Cell Menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the comments notwithstanding, I think there may be an acceptable compromise between notational simplicity and formal accuracy. It involves defining functions really as `Function`, not by patterns.

Here is an example of how that looks in `TraditionalForm`. It's the replacement for the standard definition `a[x_]:= Sin[x]`, now written in a notation that you'll find in almost that same form in math texts:

```
a = {x} \[Function] sin(x)

(* ==> Function[{x}, Sin[x]] *)
```

Here, I've entered the symbol `↦` as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`fn`<kbd>Esc</kbd> and it's displayed above as `\[Function]`. I'm **assuming** this is entered in `TraditionalForm`. So what you actually see in the notebook is

```
a = {x} ↦ sin(x)
```

which (depending on your background) might be a familiar way of writing a function definition. At least you don't have to worry about how to hide or modify the underscore that would be required in the pattern based type of function definition.

The function is of course invoked the same way you always do it. In `TraditionalForm` again, that would be

```
a(π/2)

(* ==> 1 *)
```